# VisualStateManager fails to start animation on UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, visualstatemanager

I'm trying to start a animation on a UserControl using the VisualStateManager in a Windows Phone 7 Silverlight project but it won't work. GoToState just keep returning false.

The code consists of a VisualState-behaviour which is running the GoToState when a State-property on the datacontext is changed, which happens when the button in the UI is clicked:

What am I doing wrong?

XAML:

```
    <Grid>
        <UserControl x:Name="_testSubject" l:VisualStates.CurrentState="{Binding State}" />
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Change state" Click="Button_Click" />
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="State2">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation From="Red" To="Green" Duration="0:0:10" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="_testSubject" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
```

C#:

```
public class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged(string name) { if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name)); }
    string _state;
    public string State { get { return _state; } set { _state = value; OnPropertyChanged("State"); } }
}

public static class VisualStates
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentStateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CurrentState", typeof(String), typeof(VisualStates), new PropertyMetadata(TransitionToState));

    public static string GetCurrentState(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(CurrentStateProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCurrentState(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(CurrentStateProperty, value);
    }

    private static void TransitionToState(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Control c = sender as Control;
        if (c != null)
        {
            bool b = VisualStateManager.GoToState(c, (string)args.NewValue, false);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("CurrentState is only supported on the Control type");
        }
    }

public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public MainPage() { InitializeComponent(); }

    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _testSubject.DataContext = new Test();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Test)_testSubject.DataContext).State = "State2";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just a wild guess, but could it be that it is being executed in the wrong thread? You might want to use the dispatcher to execute it on the correct (UI) thread.

Does the GoToState work in the Button_Click function ?

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool b = VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "State2", false);
}
```

And is TransitionToState being called when you execute your code.

This would rule out any other problems.

**UPDATE**

The following works for me. I came accross some problems with setting the Background. First of all this doesn't have any effect on a UserControl and second it is not possible to change the background using a Color animation that's why I change the opacity.

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"
      Grid.Row="1"
      Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <l:TestControl x:Name="_testSubject"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   l:VisualStates.CurrentState="{Binding State}" />

    <UserControl x:Name="_test2Subject"
                 Height="100"
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 l:VisualStates.CurrentState="{Binding State}">
        <Grid x:Name="aLayoutRoot"
              Background="Wheat">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="State2">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="aLayoutRoot"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                             From="1"
                                             To="0"
                                             Duration="0:0:2"
                                             AutoReverse="True" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>

    <Button Click="Button_Click"
            Content="Click"
            Grid.Row="2" />


</Grid>
```

TestControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="PhoneApp1.TestControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Wheat">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="State2">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         From="1"
                                         To="0"
                                         Duration="0:0:2"
                                         AutoReverse="True" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Test.cs / TransitionToState method

```
private static void TransitionToState(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    UserControl c = sender as UserControl;
    if (c != null && args.NewValue != null)
    {
        bool b = VisualStateManager.GoToState(c, (string)args.NewValue, true);
        var a = b;
    }
}
```

MainPage.cs

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _testSubject.DataContext = new Test();
    _test2Subject.DataContext = new Test();

}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Test)_testSubject.DataContext).State = "State2";
    ((Test)_test2Subject.DataContext).State = "State2"; 
}
```

I would also recommend using ControlTemplates to assign VisualStates instead of defining them directly on the control. This will give you more flexibility, better maintenance, etc..

Hope this helps.

Comment: GoToState is still returning false, even in Button_Click.

Comment: Weird, I can't even put a Grid in a UserControl. It doesn't support direct content it says. Tried with a ContentControl instead but that didn't solve the problem anyway. GoToState is still returning false. Thanks for your effort though. I've moved on with another approach instead.

Comment: But putting it in a separate UserControl worked better, including animation! Very strange.

Comment: I need to note that i'm using the latest 'Mango' SDK. So this might explain some differences.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue I found a solution that helped me and may be someone find it useful
if the usercontrol is hosted in layoutawarepage

```
<my:usercontrole Loaded="StartLayoutUpdates" Unloaded="StopLayoutUpdates" />
```

otherwise you will have to de the follow (example can be found in the layout aware page)

- make event handler on sizechanged
- in the event handler check the viewstate with ApplicationView.Value
- move to that state with VisualStateManager.GoToState

Edit: Sorry for misunderstanding I thought that it is winRT App